# RestSharp выкидывает NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, restsharp

В общем, стучусь на некоторый ресурс, дергая вот этот метод:

```
RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsync(this RestSharp.IRestClient client, RestSharp.IRestRequest request, System.Action<RestSharp.IRestResponse> callback)
```

А дальше в callback обрабатываю response.

Проблема в том, что есть 10% response к этому ресурсу, которые приходятся со StatusCode=0 и исключением:

```
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at RestSharp.Http.GetRawResponseAsync(IAsyncResult result, Action`1 callback)
  at RestSharp.Http.ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result, Action`1 callback)
```

и пустым контентом.

Т.е похоже, что проблема в RestSharp (использую последнюю версию).
Нашел вот такой [тред](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/552), но ответов на вопросы я не получил. Однако понять, что ему не нравится, я не могу, так как запрос корректен и успешно выполняется через cURL.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Глядя в исходники можно заметить, что в самой новой версии RestSharp этот метод помечен как `[Obsolete("Use ExecuteAsync that returns Task")]`. Но при этом подходящего метода, который бы возвращал Task, и в который можно было бы передать `callback` я не смог найти. Наиболее подходящий метод `RestClient` также помечен как `Obsolete`, и он все равно возвращает `RestRequestAsyncHandle`:

```
[Obsolete("This method will be removed soon in favour of the proper async call")]
public virtual RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsync(
            IRestRequest request,
            Action<IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle> callback,
            Method httpMethod
```

**UPD.**
Я сразу не обратил внимания на тип делегата `callback`. Пользуйтесь этим методом класса `RestClient`:

```
public Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteAsync(
            IRestRequest request,
            Method httpMethod,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```